# Is the computer BIOS specific to an architecture

Tags: cpu, bios

Is the BIOS manufactured with the processor in mind?

Suppose I have a 32Bit Intel processor and I wish to to upgrade to a 64 Bit Intel later. (Assume this is possible & not just a switch replacement).

As the x86 instruction set is a subset of x64 set, I guess the same BIOS would be enough to power on 64Bit the Operating System.

Am I right in assuming so and is there any reasons I shouldn't do this?

Comment: The BIOS is written specifically for your motherboard. It configures the specific hardware on your motherboard and possibly loads microcode for the specific CPU types that motherboard supports. Another x86 board/cpu would probably be able to execute the code, but the code would be trying to write to registers and apply setting that don't even exist on the other platform.

Comment: BIOS is a PC-AT legacy, so it's limited to a very old version of x86, i286 iirc. About a decade ago x86 and x86-64 co-existed for a while, e.g. LGA775 and socket 754 generation.

Comment: @user1320881 : Forget manufacturer. I am assuming compatible architectures from same manufacturer like ia-32 & ia-64. In my specific case should  there be a  problem  with `but the code would be trying to write to registers and apply setting that don't even exist on the other platform`?

Comment: @user3528438 : ` a decade ago x86 and x86-64 co-existed for a while `. Why did they cease to exist together then?

Comment: @sjsam : Yes, even 2 near identical motherboards from the same manufacturer can have subtle differences like a different voltage regulator chip for the CPU, requiring a change in the BIOS code that talks to the chip to configure voltages. Any tiny hardware difference can require a BIOS modification.

Comment: @user1320881 : Valid point.. :D . I overlooked the power aspect.

Comment: As for the difference between 32 and 64 bit CPU's. They run different micro-code and that is loaded into the CPU by the bios. Also the CPU itself has configuration registers and even part of the chipset (north bridge is now inside the CPU) which are configured by the bios and can totally change from one CPU to the next.

Comment: @user1320881 :  That makes BIOS very much architecture specific as it was already motherboard specific.  I see..

Comment: IA32 and IA64 are completely different families and IA64 actually does not use BIOS (it uses EFI/UEFI). X86-64 and X86 still co-exist in a different form: x64-64 CPU can always run in X86 mode, but pure X86 CPUs are no longer mainstream. LGA775 generation has both x86-64 and X86 because intel implemented X86-64 as an extension of existing LGA775 CPUs, so they share package and motherboards. Socket 754 generation is because AMD tried to differentiate their low end product by disabling X86-64 support and reducing L2 cache.

Comment: @user1320881: The same CPU doesn't need a different voltage to run in 32 or 64bit mode.  64bit OSes can run 64 and 32bit processes at the same time on a multi-core CPU.  Similarly, microcode is specific the the CPU microarchitecture, not to all 64bit CPUs vs. all 32bit CPUs.  e.g. there aren't separate microcode updates for 32 and 64bit for Intel IvyBridge stepping XX.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A lot of the comments on the question are bogus.  Every CPU that can run in x86-64 long mode can run a 16bit or 32bit OS.  There are no x86-64 CPUs that dropped 32bit support.  (Intel's architecture manual PDFs are on their web site, see the Stackoverflow [x86 tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info).)

AFAIK, the BIOS can only be used in 16bit mode, so after an OS boots and switches the CPU to 32bit protected mode, or 64bit long mode, the BIOS doesn't matter.  The OS needs drivers to talk to hardware directly.

AFAIK, **any motherboard that can boot a 64bit-capable CPU will work in 64bit mode.**  The CPU doesn't need to run at a different voltage or anything in 64bit mode.  So just check your mobo's CPU compatibility list.

The BIOS / UEFI firmware shipped with a motherboard is specific to that motherboard and the CPUs it supports, not to x86-32 or x86-64.  There is at least one project ([Coreboot, formerly LinuxBios](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coreboot)) aimed at developing open-source firmware to replace vendor BIOSes, but it has to be ported specifically to every different piece of hardware in a machine.

---

There are no longer any mainstream x86 CPUs that don't support x86-64 mode.  The last one was [probably Atom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Atom#32-bit_and_64-bit_hardware_support), but those don't come in socketed packages, AFAIK, so upgrading an Atom board to a newer 64bit CPU is out of the question.

For desktop CPUs, there were motherboards that could support both 32bit-only CPUs and 64bit-capable CPUs.  [Socket 478](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Socket_478) was used by P4 Northwood and Willamette (32bit), and early [P4 Prescott](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentium_4#Prescott) (Intel's first IA-32e aka x86-64 CPU).  Later P4s used LGA 775, which was also used by Core2.

Any system you'd consider buying these days supports 64bit mode, even if it's still sold with obsolete 32bit-only software installed.  (Or it's a tiny thing with a 32bit-only CPU soldered in).